# What is the Hugo permalink format to exactly match the Blogger permalink format?

Tags: blogger, permalinks, hugo

I am attempting to migrate from Blogger to Hugo hosted on Google App Engine. An example url I am attempting to rebuild:

> https://www.darianhickman.com/2017/03/one-year-of-uber-lyft-2016-5300.html

In my config.toml file I am trying:

```
[permalinks]
  post  = "/:year/:month/:title.html"
```

It's close but fails. Example Hugo generated url:

> http://localhost:1313/2017/03/one-year-of-uber--lyft-2016-5300.html/

Hugo's default behavior is to make posts into folders with an index.html. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hugo's default behavior is to make posts into folders with an index.html. What do I need to change?

In your configuration file (typically named `config.toml`) you'll need to enable the feature called 'ugly URLs' like so:

```
uglyURLs = true
```

Doing so makes Hugo create URLs in form of `/my-post.html`. By default, Hugo makes those `index.html` files you mention for `/my-post/` kind of URLs.

Comment: That got first problem solved thank you! Then I ran into issues that blogger caps the number of words in a filename.  Do you know how to make hugo match those filename endings?  I might be barking up the wrong

Comment: Hugo cannot limit the number of words that appear in a permalink, like Blogger seems to do (if I understand your comment correctly, I'm unfamiliar with Blogger lately).